# StreamWriter doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a program that reads a CSV, and replaces its values.

I use the same file, it reads the file, extracts the data, populates a DataTable, then reconstructs the data to be re-written into the CSV with no issues, but when I check the CSV, it's empty.

It doesn't matter if I use the same file, or create a new file, they all come up empty.

Here is my Write Method:

```
void RewriteCSV(DataTable table)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
    sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;

    // If no File is selected, the program ends.
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);

    string line = "";

    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        line += col.ColumnName + ",";
    }
    writer.WriteLine(line.TrimEnd(','));

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        line = "";
        foreach (string s in row.ItemArray)
        {
            line += s + ",";
        }
        writer.WriteLine(line.TrimEnd(','));
    }
}
```

Again, the program has no problems with the data, or the files, it just doesn't write to the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close the file and make sure it flushes to disk

The easiest way is wrap it in a using statment

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
{

    //do stuff here
    ...
    ...

} // this closes and flushes the file to disk
```

**Some additional reading**

[StreamWriter.Flush Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data
>   to be written to the underlying stream.

[FileStream.Flush Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bw4h516(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Clears buffers for this stream and causes any buffered data to be
>   written to the file.

[StreamWriter.Close Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Closes the current StreamWriter object and the underlying stream.
>   You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out
>   to the underlying stream. Following a call to Close, any operations on
>   the StreamWriter might raise exceptions. If there is insufficient
>   space on the disk, calling Close will raise an exception.

[using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

**Exmaple**

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt"))
{
    writer.Write("Word ");
    writer.WriteLine("word 2");
    writer.WriteLine("Line");
}
```

**Update**

> Oh, so it doesn't "save" until you close the stream?

A `StreamWriter` opening with those arguments is backed by a `FileStream`, it will not save unless it has auto-flushed or you flush it. This will happen when you close, and close will happen when you dispose. Rule of thumb, if it is disposable, always use a `using` statement

Comment: Yup. Didn't close it, that's what I was missing. Didn't realise that's necessary for it to "save". Thanks!